# Verify URL exists from file

Tags: python

So I have some code that I use to scrape through my mailbox looking for certain URL's.  Once this is completed it creates a file called links.txt

I want to run a script against that file to get an output of all the current URL's that are live in that list. The script I have only allows for me to check on URL at a time

```
import urllib2

for url in ["www.google.com"]:

    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print connection.getcode()
        connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.getcode()
```

Comment: So, you just need to know how to read lines from a text file?

Answer (score 4):

Use requests:

```
import requests

with open(filename) as f:
    good_links = []
    for link in file:
        try:
            r = requests.get(link.strip())
        except Exception:
            continue
        good_links.append(r.url) #resolves redirects
```

You can also consider extracting the call to requests.get into a helper function:

```
def make_request(method, url, **kwargs):
    for i in range(10):
        try:
            r = requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)
            return r
        except requests.ConnectionError as e:
            print e.message
        except requests.HTTPError as e:
            print e.message
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            print e.message
    raise Exception("requests did not succeed")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial to make this change, given that you're already iterating over a list of URLs:

```
import urllib2

for url in open("urllist.txt"):   # change 1

    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(url.rstrip())   # change 2
        print connection.getcode()
        connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.getcode()
```

Iterating over a file returns the lines of the file (complete with line endings). We use `rstrip()` on the URL to strip off the line endings.

There are other improvements you can make. For example, some will suggest you use `with` to make sure your file is closed. This is good practice but probably not necessary in this script.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2

for url in open("ZeuS_links"):   # change 1

    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(url.rstrip())   # change 2
        print connection.getcode()
        connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.getcode()

Comment: Kindall thanks for the assistance the script is now working only thing I would like to find out now is instead of 200 or 401 just push out the actual urls I will continue to work with it and update as I go thanks again for your help

Comment: You already have `url` as the URL you're trying to retrieve; just print that.

Comment: that did it sometimes the small things are right in front of you.  Thanks alot kindall.  Awesome Awesome Awesome